# Handling Memory Limit on a Process in C#

Tags: c#, process, memory-limit

I have a main application calling another console application through Process component. I have set a memory limit on the console app using through custom implementation of Job Objects(Class name as 'Job' in the code)

Whenever the memory limit is crossed OutofMemory exception is thrown or KERNELBASE.DLL faulting happens. But I am unable to catch this exception in the main app or in the console app.

What is the way to handle this ?

Handling through Global exception in console app did not work.

Main Application has following code

```
private void startProcess()
    {
        try
        {                              
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\App\console.exe";            
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_OutputDataReceived;
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += Proc_ErrorDataReceived;
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.Start();              
            Job job = new Job(_maxmemory);//memory limit set for child process
            job.AddProcess(proc.Id);//for the above console
            proc.WaitForExit();//this is called on a thread.         

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Console app has following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
            System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CatchUnhandledException;
  }
static void CatchUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());

        }
```

How to handle this memory limit exception either in main app or console ?

Comment: Is this `Job` class a .NET type? I cannot find a class of that name in the .NET framework matching the behavior you intend there.

Comment: @PMF ```c# Job``` it is the custom implementation of Job Objects which takes maximum memory limit to be used for child process.

Comment: Never seen them before, is this what you are talking about? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, the link that you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Your main app code clearly will not catch that error. `Process.Start()` starts the other process asynchonously, so the method will end before the other process really does something. You'll have to call `proc.WaitForExit()` if you want to wait for the child process to terminate. After that, you can use the `ExitCode` property to find out whether your child process had an error. The value will be non-zero if your process died due to an exception.

Code such as this one in the *child* process should actually work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try 
    {
        AllocateALotOfMemory();
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryException e)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: Allocation of memory for child process happens in main app and not in child process. Can the catch block handle `OutOfMemoryException` in this case ?

Comment: I have never seen or used this Job api, but I don't think the memory is allocated by the main app, even in this case. The job just sets some limits which the operating system will enforce. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you have to limit the memory usage of the child processes (instead of checking that they don't use too much memory in the first place)? I have the feeling your approach is way to complicated.